# Android Studio LoginActivity with MySQL - attempt authentication against a network service

Tags: java, android, mysql

I'm still fairly new to Android Studio. I'm trying to use the LoginActivity to input user's email and password when they want to login/register to the MySQL database (with phpMyAdmin). My code right now can only login using static variables, see below code.

In the LoginActivity.java, I was given this code to test the login using static variables:

```
//A dummy authentication store containing known user names and passwords.
//TODO: remove after connecting to a real authentication system.

private static final String[] DUMMY_CREDENTIALS = new String[]{
        "foo@example.com:hello", "bar@example.com:world"
};
```

There's also this part in the LoginActivity.java which I don't really understand:

```
@Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.

        try {
            // Simulate network access.
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return false;
        }

        for (String credential : DUMMY_CREDENTIALS) {
            String[] pieces = credential.split(":");
            if (pieces[0].equals(mEmail)) {
                // Account exists, return true if the password matches.
                return pieces[1].equals(mPassword);
            }
        }

        // TODO: register the new account here.
        return false; //CHANGED
    }
```

Full LoginActivity.java [here](https://github.com/linahsie/foodzilla/blob/master/LoginActivity.java)

Which part of the LoginActivity do I need to change in order for it to login and register user from mySQL database instead of static variables? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand why you need those static variable. But if you want to login or register a user to your MYSQL data which you need is to make a HTTP request, forget those static variable. Since you mention about phpMyadmin I assume you have some knowledge regarding PHP you can set up a localhost server with XMAPP(window) or MAMP(osx).

There is a lot of way you can sending data to your own server but the easiest is to use 3rd party library which I recommend [Android Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html).

For login you need to make a query to check wether the username and password pass to the server is really exists. For register just insert new record to your database. If you didn't know what is HTTP request get started [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

Comment: Thanks! What should I change in the doInBackground function?

Comment: The static variable was given to me when I chose to have the LoginActivity template. It's for testing whether the login works or not using, for example, email: foo@example.com with password:hello. Also, where should I put the HTTP request thing? Is it in the java file in Android Studio or in my php file? I do have my php file here [link] (https://github.com/linahsie/foodzilla/blob/master/Login.php) and I have some POST methods.

Comment: Sorry for late reply.. If you use android volley to make http request call you don't have to worry about any AsyncTask. Android volley run in a separate thread. The link I provide you got all information you need to get started, don't rush more your rush the more confuse u will get